# Extending the GUI from plugins in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails3

I have a requirement where new items should be added to the menu of an app when different plugins are installed. The key idea is to extend the frontend functionality with plugins, adding new items on the menu will allow to access actions from controllers defined on those plugins installed.

I couldn't find any documentation or guide that talks about that, and not sure if it's any recommendation on that area. Also I need to validate if this could be done with plugins and if there is any better alternative than plugins.

Also, I want to avoid at all costs is creating my own plugin infrastructure inside Grails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default generated `grails-app/views/index.gsp` for a newly created Grails app actually does that.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Installed Plugins <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <g:each var="plugin" in="${applicationContext.getBean('pluginManager').allPlugins}">
            <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">${plugin.name} - ${plugin.version}</a></li>
        </g:each>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I hope that helps.

**EDIT: Adding Info Based On Comment Below**

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosmenus.

Run the app...

```
./gradlew app:bootRun
```

On the main home page you will see a "Books" menu and a "Music" menu.

The app depends on 2 plugins, each of those plugins is providing dynamic menu info.  The plugins are being pulled into the app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosmenus/blob/345bcf17a12639df6b7c9e980c39f01102f1eb2c/app/build.gradle#L62-L63.

```
runtime project(':pluginone')
runtime project(':plugintwo')
```

`pluginone` is providing the "Music" menu.  `plugintwo` is proving the "Books" menu.  If you comment out either of those plugin dependencies and re-run the app, you will see the corresponding menu disappear in the app.  This indicates that the app is dynamically building up the menu based on beans provided by the plugins.  The simple tag library at https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosmenus/blob/master/app/grails-app/taglib/pablopazosmenus/MenuTagLib.groovy is part of that.

```
package pablopazosmenus

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired

class MenuTagLib {

    static namespace = 'pablo'

    @Autowired
    List<MenuHelper> menuHelpers

    def renderMenu = { attrs ->
        out << render(template: '/dynamicMenu', model: [menuHelpers: menuHelpers])
    }
}
```

The plugins are each providing 1 of the `MenuHelper` beans that are being injected there but a plugin could provide any number of those.  Each of the plugins is adding the beans in their `doWithSpring` methods.

The code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/pablopazosmenus/blob/345bcf17a12639df6b7c9e980c39f01102f1eb2c/app/grails-app/views/index.gsp#L36 is invoking that tag lib.

```
<pablo:renderMenu/>
```

There are a lot of different ways to put all this together and how I would do it would depend on understanding the real requirements.

I hope that helps.

Comment: That lists the plugins installed, but how the plugins can add items to the app menu, I'm taking about an app that has some funcrionality accessed from a menu on the gsp and if a plugin is installed, it can add many extra items to that menu to access new functionality (controllers and views defined in those new plugins).

Comment: The question is quite vague. One possibility is that the plugins providing the functionality could provide beans that describe the capability and you could have a TagLib into which you insert all instances of those beans and that tag lib generates the relevant menus.

Comment: Do you know where can I find an example of your recommendation? I can add more details to the question, but that is the basic requirement: when a plugin is installed, get more items on the GUI (buttons, links, etc on some menu) that allow to access functionality added by those plugins (controllers, services, views, etc), this without hardcoding stuff on the base app (most plugins work this way, to extend the framework used to build the app, what I need is to actually extend the app, and try to do it using plugins if possible).

Comment: I created a sample project and described the key points in an update to the answer above.  Obviously there is a lot you could do here like add support for relative menu positioning/ordering, sub-menus etc... but I think that example demonstrates the plumbing in a way that shows you some options to think about.

Comment: wow, thanks, let me check that! BTW thanks for the namespace ;)

Comment: I see, the magic happens here:


    @Autowired
    List<MenuHelper> menuHelpers

Didn't know that Spring could inject all instances of a certain type without extra configuration, that is certainly magic. And yes, Rush rocks! Thank you.